# How to pass javascript variable to a django template tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have created a template tag and that will accept 2 arguments, returns a text. Currently, I am not able to pass a javascript variable value to django template tag. can you help me over here?

**javascript code with template tag**

```
function formatState (state) {
        if (!state.id) {
            return state.text;
        }
        console.log(state.text);
        var x = "{% get_data state.text 'account' %}";
        var $state = $('<span class="badge">' + x + '</span>');
        return $state;
    }
```

**Template Tag**

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_data(value, module):
    *****
    x = "hello"
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Django template is rendered on the server, then sent to the client where you JS is run. You can't access JS variables from the server in your templates because they don't exist there.

If you need to access data from your front end with Django, you can create a view function that will take a POST request and send you data to you server with JS and then return some template that you can add to your page with JS.